# How do I get all data associated with a nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models: `Quiz`, which `has_many` `questions`, which `has_many` `answers`. The lower models all `belongs_to` the model intuitively above them (quiz > questions > answers).

My problem is that I want to get a collection of all the answers. I thought I could do this with something like `quiz.questions.answers` or `quiz.questions.all.answers` but I just get an error `undefined method 'answers'`. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Answer` belongs to one `Question` so you cannot call `answers` on a collection of `questions`, so if you want all the answers of all the questions of a quiz then you can do something like this to achieve, in `Quiz` model add this

```
has_many :answers, through: :questions
```

By adding that you will be able to fetch all the answers directly by doing `quiz.answers`.

Now, if you want to get answers of specific questions then you can do something like this

```
quiz = Quiz.where(id: quiz_id).include(:questions => :answers)
quiz.questions.each do |question|
  answers = question.answers
  # perform some action
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: oh boy okay so I thought it was probably that... but I was hoping it wasn't because won't I have to change the table data around? Right now, according to my current associations, `answers` has a `question_id` and `questions` has NO `answer_id`. If I add `has_many :answers, through: :questions` I'll have to take out `question_id` from `answers` and add an `answer_id` to `questions`, right? That poses a bit of a problem for me since I'm relying on the fact that `answers` has a `question_id` for a few of my methods.

Comment: No, you won't have to change anything at the database level, since you already have `has_many :questions` in your `Quiz` model, by adding `has_many :answers, through: :questions`, ActiveRecord will allow you to get all the `answers` belonging to a `quiz`. Try it once!

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense to me, but then why does the rubyonrails official (?) guide make it seem like the intervening model (in their case, `appointments`, need both of the other id's? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: That is an example of `many-to-many` association, but in your case its `one-to-many` so that intervening model is not needed here. You need ids of both in an intervening table if you want a `many-to-many` relation, right?

Comment: right, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect example of something that needs a "through" association.

```
class Quiz
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, :through => :questions
```

Then:

```
my_quiz.answers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

Then you can have,
quiz = Quiz.last

quiz.questions
quiz.answers
```